# Crystal Report randomly breaks when setting parameter value

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have searched high and low for a fix to this, so I apologize in advance if this is a dumb question or a repeat question.

So I have this Crystal Report, no I unfortunately do not know the version I'm on, that works most of the time and randomly breaks under the exact same conditions as when it works. On the times that it breaks, when I go to set the parameter with ApplyCurrentValue, it immediately pops up a window that asks for all parameters (as if none were set).  When I press exit, it breaks with

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(ParameterValues
>   currentValues)

Below is the code.  Also, every parameter I pass is the correct value so none of them are null and actually have a value.

```
rpt.SetDataSource(ds)
crv.ReportSource = rpt

AddCrystalReportParameters("EntityName", entityName)
AddCrystalReportParameters("dtFrom", datFrom.ToShortDateString())
AddCrystalReportParameters("dtTo", datTo.ToShortDateString())
AddCrystalReportParameters("RectEntityDesc", rectEntityDesc)
```

Here is the method that I use.

```
Sub AddCrystalReportParameters(ByVal sFieldName As String, ByVal sValue As String)
    Dim discreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue()
    Dim values As New ParameterValues()

    values = rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields(sFieldName).CurrentValues()
    discreteValue.Value = sValue 'Assign parameter
    values.Add(discreteValue)
    rpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields(sFieldName).ApplyCurrentValues(values)
End Sub
```

Because it is so random for when it breaks, it has made testing it extremely difficult. I was thinking that maybe the report isn't loaded, but I checked for rpt.IsLoaded in which it said it was even though it went on to break when it went to add the parameter.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to set parameters if you are setting the datasource using SetDataSource

Comment: I think I do in this case.  The dates are values entered in by a user so they will be whatever the user wants them to be, thus I have to pass it in to the Crystal Report.

Answer (score 0):

First Create Parameters in the report itself with names (EntityName,dtFrom,dtTo and RectEntityDesc) as you described. then add these parameters to your report as objects then in the code you can set the values as code below:

```
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@EntityName", EntityName)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@dtFrom", dtFrom.SelectedDate)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@dtTo", dtTo.SelectedDate)
    rpt.SetParameterValue("@RectEntityDesc", rectEntityDesc)
```

this code used because you have already added the parameters to the report you are only setting the value of each parameter.

Comment: I tried that and it sadly didn't work either.  It's so weird and so random of why it breaks.  It works sometimes, and not other times.

Comment: What are the conditions that you are talking about in the question?? does it break if the parameters or one of the is null??